# Getting values from string with Regex (Regular Expressions) in C#

Tags: c#, regex, string, expression

I would like to get some values from a string with Regex. I'll proceed to explain:

- There is a string: "Player #0 Agentep97 (12.34.56.78:1234) connected"
- I'd like to get the #[NUMBER], Username ("Agentep97"), ([IP]:[Port]) values

I already tried with `var match = Regex.Match(input, @"Player #(?<player_id>[0-9]{1,3})\s(?<user>.+)\s\((<ip1>\d{1,3})\.(<ip2>\d{1,3})\.(<ip3>\d{1,3})\.(<ip4>\d{1,3})\:(<port>\d{1,5}$)\) connected\W\D\S", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);` but I the Match didn't succeed so I couldn't get player_id.Value and such.

How would you do it? Is "var match" not correct or anything?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regular expressions can be frustrating for this very reason: it's often an all or nothing with no clear explanation why it isn't working.  What I would suggest is how I went about reviewing your regular expression.  I added in one character/group at a time until it stopped matching (using the very helpful and mostly .NET-compatible tool [Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/)), and then looked at what broke the regular expression.  In this case, it looks like you just forgot the `?` in the named groups `ip1`, `ip2`, `ip3`, `ip4`, and `port`:

```
Player #(?<player_id>[0-9]{1,3})\s(?<user>.+)\s\(
(?<ip1>\d{1,3})\.(?<ip2>\d{1,3})\.(?<ip3>\d{1,3})\.(?<ip4>\d{1,3})\:(?<port>\d{1,5}$)\) connected\W\D\S
 ^                ^                ^                ^                ^
```

Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/J8dEEE3HnC

Comment: Rubular isn't .NET compatible at all, it's just that they have a lot of regex features/syntax in common. [regexhero](http://regexhero.net) might be interesting

Comment: Lots of thanks! Worked perfectly! I would like to Upvote but I have no reputation, thanks anyway!!! :)

Comment: @HamZa: That's what I meant.  The syntax is largely similar so it works pretty good for rapid prototyping.  I didn't know about regexhero, so thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: `RegexBuddy` is also very great!

Comment: Thanks! I'll also try it and tell you what

Comment: @ShadowHunter: if you don't have silverlight, you can use regexstorm.net

Answer (score 3):

You can use this pattern:

```
Player #(?<number>[0-9]+) (?<username>\S+) \((?<ip>(?>[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}):(?<port>[0-9]+)\)
```

I don't think you need to catch all separate numbers of the IP address.

An other way is to use the split method with this pattern:

```
[)]?[ :][#(]?
```